# Python pandas how to sum values by accumulation while zeroing when changing the sign (+,-)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file with some calculations that looks something like this:

| Value1 |
| --- |
| -1 |
| -4 |
| -5 |
| -2 |
| -3 |
| -6 |
| 1 |
| 7 |
| 5 |
| 8 |
| 2 |
| -1 |
| 2 |
| -3 |

I would like to add a new column to it with a cumulative calculation that takes into account the sign in the Value1 column so that something like this would turn out:

| Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- |
| -1 | -1 |
| -4 | -5 |
| -5 | -10 |
| -2 | -12 |
| -3 | -15 |
| -6 | -21 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 7 | 8 |
| 5 | 13 |
| 8 | 21 |
| 2 | 23 |
| -1 | -1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| -3 | -3 |

That is, for example, while there is a negative value in the Value 1 column, there is an addition in the Value2 column (x + (-x1)) where x is the value Value1 and -x1 is the previous value in the column Value2 and when the sign in the column Value 1 is changed, the calculation begins anew

Is this possible with Python and Pandas?

Comment: what is your desired output? it will be easy to understand what you want.

Comment: I want for example if there are 3 rows in the Value 1 column (-1,-3,-1) then in the Value 2 column it would be -1 (-1+0) , -4(+((-3-1)Previous column value Value2), -5(-4+(-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

# read your csv
fname = 'mypath/myfile.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(fname)

# pd.Series with False for neg vals / True for pos vals
positives = df.Value1 >= 0

# pd.Series with consecutive count groups
sequences = (positives != positives.shift()).cumsum()

# now perform `groupby` on these groups, and assign to df.Value2
df['Value2'] = df.groupby(sequences)['Value1'].cumsum()

print(df)

    Value1  Value2
0       -1      -1
1       -4      -5
2       -5     -10
3       -2     -12
4       -3     -15
5       -6     -21
6        1       1
7        7       8
8        5      13
9        8      21
10       2      23
11      -1      -1
12       2       2
13      -3      -3

# save to csv again
df.to_csv(fname, index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

First identify where the rows change sign with a mask. Then groupby them and use `cumsum`:

```py
pos_or_neg = df['Value1'] >= 0
groups = pos_or_neg.diff().ne(0).cumsum()
print(groups)
```

The groups look like this:

```
0     1
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     1
5     1
6     2
7     2
8     2
9     2
10    2
11    3
12    4
13    5
Name: Value2, dtype: int32
```

Finally:

```
df['Value2'] = df.groupby(groups)['Value1'].cumsum()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    Value1  Value2
0       -1      -1
1       -4      -5
2       -5     -10
3       -2     -12
4       -3     -15
5       -6     -21
6        1       1
7        7       8
8        5      13
9        8      21
10       2      23
11      -1      -1
12       2       2
13      -3      -3
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to use [`run-length encoding`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) via package [`python-rle`](https://pypi.org/project/python-rle/):

```
import rle

r = rle.encode(np.sign(df['Value1']))

df['Value2'] = df.groupby(rle.decode([*range(1, len(r[0])+1)], r[1])).cumsum()
```

Output:

```
    Value1  Value2
0       -1      -1
1       -4      -5
2       -5     -10
3       -2     -12
4       -3     -15
5       -6     -21
6        1       1
7        7       8
8        5      13
9        8      21
10       2      23
11      -1      -1
12       2       2
13      -3      -3
```